# How to implement facebook login in firebase react native android app?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

i have to provide facebook login functionality in my react native android app but have no clue how to implement it ... i'm using firebase . i tried signInWithRedirect and signInWithPopup with no luck ... i know that those functions are for the web but what should i do ? maybe you can guide me to a way to implement fb login with firebase or any other solution possible .
if i have to implement it using java then it'S okay but i would appreciate it if you can give me a step by step solution :D

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution , you should get the access token from fbsdk and pass it to the firebase